# Generalization of $\displaystyle \int\frac{x^m}{p(x)}\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, summation, residue-calculus

How can this formula be generalized?

*Let $p(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ with real or complex roots $z_1,...,z_n$ and $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $m=0,1,...,n-1$*
$$\int\frac{x^m}{p(x)}\mathrm{d}x=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{z_i^m}{p'(z_i)}\ln(x-z_i)+C$$
Where $p'(z_i):=\left.\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}p(x)\right|_{x=z_i}\neq 0$

It is possible to generalize this formula for $m\in\mathbb{N}$? (Without considering that it must be less than $n$)

I'm pretty sure the missing piece is a summation like this

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{m}{n}\right\rfloor}q_i(x)$$

But I am not able to see a pattern.

Comment: No, this is not true. Do you mean to integrate on some closed contour?

Comment: No, I mean general integration. Can you give me an example for which the formula doesn't work? ($m< \deg(p(x))$ eh)

Comment: where do you get this formula?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition